# Get non-constant operands in LLVM

Tags: c++, llvm

Say I have an instruction like `%res = add i32 4, %var` and I want to extract only the operand `%var` because it's a variable. My question is how I can determine whether an operand is a constant number or rvalue so that I can exclude them in my pass.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `rvalue` is a C/C++ concept. It doesn't really exist in LLVM IR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop over instruction's operands using `Instruction::value_op_begin()`, `Instruction::value_op_end()`, or `Instruction::operand_values()` and use `isa<Constant>()` to test if the given operand is constant one.